# Unable to Read/write plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, writetofile

I've looked into other users similar problems but I still can't find the problem with my code.

Here is the problem.

When the app start I call a method called setupDirectory that create (or copy from app bundle if needed) one plist for names and one for configs:

```
@implementation Data

static NSString * NamePlist;
static NSString * ConfigPlist;

+(void) setupDirectory
{

    //Names
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * dataPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    dataPath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NamesPlist.plist"];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]) {
        NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"NamesPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:dataPath error:nil];
    }

    //Config
    NSString *configPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
    configPath = [configPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ConfigPlist.plist"];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:configPath]) {
        NSString *sourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ConfigPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:configPath error:nil];
    }

NamePlist = dataPath;
ConfigPlist = configPath;

}
```

Then when I need to add a name I call the method Add name to add to the plist the name:

```
+(void) addName: (NSString *) name andConfigs: (NSArray *) configs
{
    // Name

    // Get the old content of the plist file
    NSDictionary *oldContent = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:Namelist];
    // Copy the old content of the plist file to a new dictionary
    NSMutableDictionary * newContent = [oldContent mutableCopy];
    //Add the new config to the dictionary
    [newContent setObject:[NSNull null] forKey:name];
    // Set the new dictionary as the plist file
    [newContent writeToFile:NamePlist atomically:YES];

    //Configs

    oldContent = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:ConfigPlist];
    // Copy the old content of the plist file to a new dictonary
    newContent = [oldContent mutableCopy];
    //Add the new config to the dictionary
    [newContent setObject:configs forKey:name];
    // Set the new dictionary as the plist file
    [newContent writeToFile:ConfigPlist atomically:YES];
}
```

But when I need to get the information from the plist I get nothing, so it didn't write?

```
+(NSArray *) getAllNames
{
    NSDictionary * names = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:NamePlist];
    NSArray * allNames = [(NSArray*) [names allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    return allNames;
}
```

GetallNames return an empty array.

Sorry if this question has already been answered, but I really looked for and still don't know what's going wrong

**EDIT 1:**

I used the return values of writeToFile to check if anything fail.
I'm getting a YES with the writeToFile from configsPlist, but a NO with writeToFile from NamesPlist.
So I think config is working fine, but not namesPlist

**EDIT 2:**

Using the debugger I notice that `![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:configPath]` and `!fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]` are return `NO` so I'm not actually getting into these if statments.

**Solution**

Ok, I gave it another chance and tried to create with a string instead of the [NSNull null] and now it works... I thought I should use [NSNull null] to create a dictionary with null object

Comment: Hard enough to peruse all your code without you making edits every 15 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, fixing a few typos. I finished now

Comment: Make use of the return values of the `writeToFile:atomically:` methods and the `copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:` methods to see if any are failing (and use the error parameter to see why).

Comment: You should consider using the NSFileManager methods URLsForDirectory:inDomains: and URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:. which return URLs, which are the preferred format. For more information on file system utilities, see File System Programming Guide:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: I'm getting a YES with the writeToFile from configsPlist, but a NO with writeToFile from NamesPlist.
So I think config is working fine, but not namesPlist

Comment: You are skipping through the 'if' statements because the plist file has got created. If you are using simulator for debugging, once check the plist files in the corresponding folders.

Comment: Once make sure the oldContent is not a null pointer and try storing names in dictionary as a Mutable Array itself. ex:{'name' = ('Lorenzo','Piccoli','Modolo');}

Comment: I don't think you can put an `NSNull` object in a dictionary if you need to write the dictionary to a plist file. Just for a test, change the `[NSNull null]` reference to an empty string `@""`. See if that fixes the problem writing the namesPlist.

Comment: I tried to put a nsstring as object in the dic, but sutil doesnt work. Im going to take a look to the other answers later

Comment: Ok, I gave it another chance and tried to create with a string instead of the [NSNull null] and now it works... I thought I should use [NSNull null] to create a dictionary with null object

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to go to the documents directory : /Users/administrator/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/YourApp/Documents/ and check the plist every time you add any item in it. With you can confirm if the "NamesPlist.plist" and "ConfigPlist" are getting updated or not.

Comment: Ok, just did it. I can see that ConfigPlist is being modified as the program runs but not NamesPlist... any idea why?